# Get the WebView2 ResponseCode Description

Tags: vb.net, webview2

I am changing my WebBrowser to a WebView2 so that it works with Edge in my WinForm application.

I would like to be able to get the description of the WebView2 Status.  Previously I used WebBrowser.StatusText.

So far I have tried:

```
Private Sub WebView21_NavigationCompleted(sender As Object, e As CoreWebView2NavigationCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebView21.NavigationCompleted
    MsgBox(e.HttpStatusCode)
End Sub
```

But I would like to return the description of the code (e.g. 200 = OK, 404 == Not Found etc)

Please could you help?

Thanks

Comment: A simple description could be `CType(e.HttpStatusCode, HttpStatusCode).ToString()`, but of course not exactly *formatted* (though separating the parts that start with a capital letter with a space is not that complicated). Otherwise, get the descriptions from, e.g., [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) and use a `Dictionary(Of Integer, String)` to show a more comprehensive text

Comment: Check whether `e.WebErrorStatus = 0` beforehand, otherwise it's a navigation error instead